# Кастомизация полей в TabularInline Django

Tags: django, django-admin

Необходимо преобразовать текст ссылки в ссылку, при подключении таблицы через TabularInline. В самой таблице я реализовал это следующим образом

```
@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('order_link_changed',)

    def order_link_changed(self, obj):
        from django.utils.html import format_html
        return format_html('<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(obj.order_link,
                                                          'Ссылка'))

    order_link_changed.short_description = 'Ссылка на товар'
```

что в панели администратора выглядит как надо

[image: Отображение ссылки в панеле администратора django]

но в TabularInline уже такая кастомизация не работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код самого "инлайна"

```
class OrderInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Order
    fields = ('order_link', 'created')
    readonly_fields = ('created',)
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OrderInline]
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать кликабельную ссылку в TabularInline можно следующим образом

```
class OrderInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Order
    fields = ('order_link_changed',)
    readonly_fields = ('order_link_changed',)

    def order_link_changed(self, obj):
        from django.utils.html import format_html
        return format_html('<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(obj.order_link,
                                                      'Ссылка'))

    order_link_changed.short_description = 'Ссылка на товар'
```

Результат

[image: Как выглядит кликабельная ссылка в TabularInline]